# Como puedo condicionar que se muestre una imagen de baja resolucion al hacer scroll y se refleje la imagen de alta calidad al estar sin movimiento

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy realizando un proyecto **imitación de streetView**, nosotros grabamos el recorrido del barrio, en primera instancia lo hice sencillo que al hacer scroll el video se reproduzca el tema es que estaba muy pesado por la alta calidad..
entonces lo que hice fue pasarlo a fotogramas, el proyecto lo tengo terminado solo que quiero mejorarlo, y quisiera que..
cuándo haga scroll el recorrido sea visualizado x las imágenes que tengo en calidad de ***500x281 y al detenerse que se vean en la calidad 1920x1080*** ya que si lo pongo en calidad alta se pone super lenta la pagina..!!
si quieren ver el proyecto pueden ir a https://impactostereo.com/transmedia/transmedia.html

**hay alguna funcion Js para esta actividad??**

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [ask]. Por favor, incluye el código relevante directamente en tu pregunta. Si bien está permitido enlazar recursos externos, se espera que el contenido esencial de las preguntas y el de las respuestas se encuentre dentro de StackOverflow, pues los vínculos podrían romperse en el futuro. Prepara un [mcve] y tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscan serán mucho más altas.

Comment: Me parece interesante tu problema, y la solución se puede abordar de distintas maneras dependiendo de la tu implementación, por lo que es importante puedas colocar un [MRE], pero uno bueno (no copiar y pegar tu código), deberías generar un ejemplo básico que tenga la lógica de lo que estás haciendo, incluir ejemplo de imágenes y todos lo necesario para llegar y ejecutar.